# Edit files from Cyberduck in an existing Vim window

Tags: windows, vim, gvim, cyberduck

I use Cyberduck as my go to FTP client on Windows. I have but one complaint, and that is whenever I click the edit button to edit the remote file with a local version of gVim, it opens in a new window/instance of Vim. This leads to a cluttered desktop as well as not allowing the [AutoComplPop](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1879) to work at it's full potential.

What I would like to be able to do is automatically open every file in a new buffer inside of an existing gVim buffer instead of a new window, kind of like the Windows version of gVim and how it has the option to edit a file in a new buffer. Is there anyway to do this in Cyberduck/gVim setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know I'm late to the party, but I found the question and want answers around for future generations.

A workaround can be found in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936501/let-gvim-always-run-a-single-instance). I created a file called `cybervim.bat` that contains the following:

```
start "vim" /B "C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim73\gvim.exe" --remote-tab-silent %*
```

I placed that in the Vim folder, although it can go wherever you want. Select that bat file as the default text editor in Cyberduck, and voila! Any documents you open in Cyberduck will open as new tabs in the existing Gvim window. It will flash a slightly annoying command prompt window, but so far I think that's the only way to do this. If you would rather not open it as a new tab, replace `--remote-tab-silent` with `--remote-silent`.

If you want all your Cyberduck files open in a Cyberduck dedicated Gvim window, add `--servername SOMENAME`, replacing `SOMENAME` with whatever you want. That will create a Vim "server" and all Cyberduck files will open in that window.